# Angular look and feel changed after reinstalling CLI and packages

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I had to delete node_modules folder because of dependency issue and reinstall CLI and all packages. After reinstalling I've noticed application look and feel changed. First of all fonts became smaller. Second, disabled buttons used to change mouse cursor on mouse over, now they don't. Expansion panel headers are now highlighted with gray, which didn't happen before. I didn't change any of the css files in the application. After deleting node_modules I've installed CLI, bootstrap, angular material and ngx-bootstrap. Apparently I had a package I used before I didn't install now, question is what exactly? This is the current setup of packages I use:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@types/popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the diff of your `package-lock.json` before and after the `npm install`, you might see some package versions that changed significantly or some that were added / removed.

Comment: @BizzyBob Thanks, issue is I don't have version control on my project yet.